# Remaximize Tkinter window in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is is possible to stop a user from minimizing a Python Tkinter window? Or maybe just have a function that checks to see if it is minimized and if it is maximize it again.

So far I can achieve a full screen window with this method

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (sw, sh))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `<Unmap>` event and deiconify the window :

```
root.bind("<Unmap>", lambda e: root.deiconify())
```

You can also prevent your window from being resized :

```
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
```