# tkinter mac, minimize screen

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using tkinter in python for mac.

Simply put, I want to override the "minimize" button's functionality.

I'm already overriding the "X" button functionality in this fashion:

> ```
> root = Tk()
> root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', doClose)
> ```

What I tried:

I looked into the WM states and there is no `WM_ICONIFY_WINDOW` or `WM_MINIMIZE_WINDOW`. I also tried working with `WM_SAVE_YOURSELF` but couldn't catch any interrupt.

what's the best known way of making tkinter do what I want when people hit "minimze" rather than the default settings?

Thanks!

Comment: @laurencevs that is `root.overrideredirect` (you missed an extra "re")

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard `WM_PROTOCOL` message for minimization. It seems, the best solution - catching `<Unmap>` events:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print event


frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Unmap>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Related links: [1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.tcl/6QV41pC_qKY/Ov50ATLNu3YJ), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836489/running-a-command-on-window-minimization-in-tkinter), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567997/remaximize-tkinter-window-in-python)