# How does a tkinter application running under Enlightenment on Ubuntu find out if it is iconic?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

Does anyone know how a Tkinter application can tell if it is iconic/minimized when running under the Enlightenment window manager on Ubuntu?

I've found Jacob Vlijm's great answer to [Binding callbacks to minimize and maximize events in Toplevel windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583495/binding-callbacks-to-minimize-and-maximize-events-in-toplevel-windows). It works on the default desktop on Ubuntu 17.04. However, I like the Enlightenment desktop. Unfortunately, xprop (used to find the window state) always shows a state of normal rather than iconic under Enlightenment.

I think this is a problem with Enlightenment, not the original answer, or I would have commented there.

Comment: I've now seen the same issue with Gtk3 using the window state event. Under Unity desktop, the app sees an iconified window state. Under Enlightenment it does not. So I'm blaming Enlightenment E17.