# Detect if user has clicked the 'maximized' button

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to detect if user has clicked the 'maximize' button:

[image: Maximize Button]

In tkInter of course, but I don't know how.

I have tried searching through StackOverflow, The Web & tkInter documents(mostly effbot's tkinterbook), but have not found anything related to what I am trying to get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583495/binding-callbacks-to-minimize-and-maximize-events-in-toplevel-windows / http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-size.htm?

Comment: @user202729 nope.

Comment: You can remove the title bar and make your own one using frame with buttons. This way you can assign commands to those buttons

Comment: @BlackThunder nice idea, but, I am too lazy :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good way to does it using `.bind()`, so let's get started!

As we know, we can maximize the window using the command `.state('zoomed')`.

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

And we can get whatever window event by `.bind("<Configure>", my_function)`

So we can create create a simple function that catches a maximize window event, not necessarily a event by click, but it works.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter

def window_event(event):
    if root.state() == 'zoomed':
        print("My window is maximized")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Maximized")

    root.bind("<Configure>", window_event)

    root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 1: New functionality**

```
import tkinter

def window_event(event):

    if root.state() == 'zoomed':
        print("My window is maximized")

    #GET A NORMAL WINDOW EVENT
    #You can easily do this by a conditional statement, but remember if you even move the window position,
    #this conditional statement will be true, because move the window is a window event
    if root.state() == 'normal':
        print("My window is normal")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Window")
    root.geometry("620x480")

    root.bind("<Configure>", window_event)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT 2: New functionality**

```
import tkinter

count = 0

def window_event(event):
    global count 

    if root.state() == 'zoomed':
        print("My window is maximized")
        count = 0

    if root.state() == 'normal' and count < 1:
        print("My window is normal")
        count +=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Window")
    root.geometry("620x480")

    root.bind("<Configure>", window_event)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

Take a look at this links, they are another way to work with Python GUI:

- [PyGUI](https://github.com/gcewing/PyGUI)
- [PySimpleGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/)

Comment: Can you update the answer so it includes for Minimization?

Comment: When it comes to minimization it's a little bit different because you can't get the `.state()`, let me be more clear. The `root.state('iconic')` minimizes your window, but you can minimize it using the method `.iconify()` as well, so now you can get the `root.state() == iconic`, in other words you can only get the `root.state() == iconic` if you minimize your window by code using the `root.iconify()`, you can read more about it in [iconify()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method).

Obs.: If you used the `.iconify()` you can also redraw your window by `.deiconify()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I actually mean when you de-maximize(or make the window normal size) the window.

Comment: Oh, great! that's possible, I'll add a new functionality for the function `window_event(event)` that dispares a action when the window becomes a normal window.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it works(I will accept answer), but every time you drag the window, it prints out "My window is normal", is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Relax, no problem! It's difficult to fix that, because the `<Configure>` gets all window events and the `.state('normal')` are all window events. My tip for you is: maybe there is other way to solve this problem, but you should give us more detals about what you want to do.

Comment: If there is a way to fix it I will try the option, but other than that, I'm fine with your answer!

Comment: I have an idea, I know how to easily solve this problem by a count, I'll edit the post and add the new functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but Thank you very much!