# Why does a Toplevel window get destroyed when the main window is minimized?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

toplevel = Toplevel()
toplevel.attributes("-toolwindow" , 1)

mainloop()
```

In this code, when I minimize the main window and open it again, the toplevel window disappears.

Here's an image(GIF) describing my problem:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

(OS: Windows 10,
Python version: 3.9.1,
Tkinter version: 8.6)

Comment: Have you tried not setting the `-toolwindow` attribute?

Comment: Yes, the problem does not occur when I remove the `-toolwindow` attribute,  but I am using this attribute because I want to remove the minimize and maximize option in my toplevel window.

Comment: In Windows 7, the *tool* window keeps open even the main window is minimized.  So better state the platform you used.

Comment: @acw1668: I am using windows 10.

Comment: I tested in Windows 10 (Python 3.9.1) and the result is the same as when I tested in Windows 7.

Comment: @acw1668: I have posted an image(GIF) that describes my problem.

Comment: @acw1668 : Yes, you are right. The window does not disappear, instead it just goes behind all windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of acw1668, I found the answer by myself.

The top-level window does not disappear; instead, it just goes behind all the windows.

There is a way to bring it back:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def bring_window_back(e):
    toplevel.attributes('-topmost' , 1)
    toplevel.attributes('-topmost' , 0)
    
toplevel = Toplevel(root)
toplevel.attributes("-toolwindow" , 1)

root.bind("<Map>" , bring_window_back)

mainloop()
```

Note: The `<Map>` binding may not work properly on linux. If you are searching for a solution for this, please see: [Binding callbacks to minimize and maximize events in Toplevel windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583495/binding-callbacks-to-minimize-and-maximize-events-in-toplevel-windows)

Hope this helps you all.

Answer (score 1):

The toolwindow attribute is specifically designed to make the window hide when the root window hides. If you don't want that behavior, don't set that attribute.

Comment: I am using the `-toolwindow` attribute because I want to remove the minimize and maximize option in my toplevel window. If it is the `-toolwindow`attribute that is causing the problem, is there anything else I can do to remove the minimize and maximize options?

Comment: @Lenovo360:  you can set the `overrideredirect` flag which will remove the entire titlebar.

Comment: I don't want to remove the whole title bar, instead I only want to remove the minimize and maximize option. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Lenovo, yes but it probably will be system specific.